# asp classic and sql server

Tags: sql-server, vbscript, asp-classic

This is my **Asp Classic** code, I am using Sql Server as database.

I have a select query using LIKE command, however, it is not working; I don't find anything when I search for a string, although, I can find numbers !!

Here is my code:

```
<%
 ConnString="DRIVER={SQL Server}; becomes Provider=SQLNCLI10;SERVER=localhost;UID=sa;" & _
"PWD=7131931;DATABASE=cri"  
set cn = Server.CreateObject("Adodb.Connection")
cn.Open ConnString 

%>
<% search = request.form("search") %>
<% set rs = server.CreateObject("Adodb.Recordset") %>
<% strsql = " SELECT * FROM News WHERE Article_Name LIKE '% & search & %' order by Article_date Desc " %>
<% rs.CursorLocation = 3 %>
<% rs.PageSize = 4 %>
<% rs.Open strSql,cn,3,2 %>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your select statement be like this? `<% strsql = "SELECT * FROM News WHERE Article_Name LIKE '%" & search & "' order by Article_date Desc " %>`

Comment: What happens when you search for `';DROP TABLE News;--`?

Comment: <% if rs.eof then %>
No Found                  
<% end if %> ' Return rs.eof

Answer (score 0):

Your variable **search** is not concatenated to the string building your command instead it is embedded:

```
'% & search & %'
```

instead of

```
'%" & search &"%'
```

Comment: strsql = " SELECT * FROM News WHERE Article_Name LIKE '% " & search "& %'  order by Article_date Desc " Not Working -  Expected end of statement

Comment: '% " & search &" %'  the amp needs to go on the other side of the quotes

Comment: Return rs.eof and find nothing , just if i search numbers , it work! this code worked fine with access database , but not working in sql server !